# Why My IOS app simulator stops showing my app screen

Tags: ios

After running my App in Xcode IOS simulator, I can see my App and when I open it after 1 or 2 seconds, instead of showing my App it shows a blank white screen saying "Hello World!".

This is my first time Developing an App and using the iOS App simulator. Please help me with this problem. I have used different iOS device simulators but the results are the same.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little difficult to judge given that we don't see your project, but I think you put your UI code in the wrong storyboard. If you create a project from scratch with Xcode you will have a structure similar to the following one:

[image]

You have two storyboards: `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.
`LaunchScreen.storyboard` contains the "splash screen" that is the screen that is shown for just a few seconds while the application starts (like a loading screen), while `Main.storyboard` is the actual first screen of your application.

I think that you added all your UI to `LaunchScreen.storyboard` instead of `Main.storyboard` and that is why you see it only for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Since I started my project I didn't see Main.storyboard only LaunchScreen.storyboard was available. How can I add Main.storyboard in my project?

Comment: Update your question with a screenshot of your project structure, so it's easier to understand. But in this case it's probable that you're creating your Main view programmatically instead that with a storyboard

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the Main.storyboard and it worked. I was working on LaunchScreen.storyboard but now everything is fine